# Nginx proxy dynamic domain breaks links

Tags: nginx, proxy

In an internal network we have loads of servers/devices we'd like to be able to reverse proxy to from a web app. If I hard code the target IP in a location context everything works fine. For example:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass  https://172.10.10.1/;
}
```

But the moment I use a variable as the host, for example:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass  https://$arg_target/;
}
```

where `$arg_target` would be `172.10.10.1` from a URL such as `http://proxy.com?target=172.10.10.1`, the returned page loses CSS and Javascript resources, which are fundamental for the functionality we are looking for.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the links to static files in your html documents also have the target field and refer to the same domain as the document itself (proxy.com in your example)? In other words, do they look like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://proxy.com/static/some.css?target=172.10.10.1">` or like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://172.10.10.1/static/some.css">`? Are there any other locations in your configuration?

Comment: Thanks for the response Ivan.

I see where you are going with your question. Good point. The above is an over-simplification of what we want to do, though. The original idea is to have a URL such as `http://proxy.com/172.10.10.1/something/else`, then extract the IP from the $uri and use it in the `proxy_pass`. I can get that to work and get the page from the target system but the links are still broken.

I haven't been able to figure out how to make Nginx rewrite links and URLs to include the IP of the target system so CSS, etc would start with `/172.10.10.1/assets/...` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Using one domain for many different applications is a tricky approach, which may lead to a lot of different problems. For example, if two or more servers set a cookie with the same name, they will get into conflict, since cookies are set for a domain and the same domain name is shared between all applications. This will be especially inconvenient if your applications use some sort of session mechanisms that rely on cookies.

The better solution would be to use different subdomains for every application, which could be achieved with a simple Nginx configuration based on the "map" directive and a wildcard server name.

Having said that, let's get back to your original problem with static files. An acceptable solution in this case would be to implement your own sessions using cookies. The idea is to set a cookie with the target host value during the first request. Then, if some other request (like a request to a css file) doesn't have the target argument, you could use the value of that cookie to determine the server to proxy the request to.

Sketchily, this type of configuration can be presented as follows:

```
server {
    ...

    set $target "$arg_target";

    if ($target = "") {
        set $target "$cookie_target";
    }

    add_header Set-Cookie "target=$target; path=/; domain=$host; max-age=3600";

    location / {
        proxy_pass  https://$target;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but couldn't make it work. I doubt that using a variable in the proxy_pass directive would work, though. While this works:

    server {  
        location / {  
            proxy_pass  https://172.10.10.1/;  
        }  
    }  

This doesn't:

    server {  
        set $ip "172.10.10.1";  
        location / {  
            proxy_pass  https://$ip/;  
        }  
    }  

Why the behavior difference? Either I found a bug in Nginx (I doubt it) or I don't understand enough about how proxying works.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried to format the configurations any possible way but I just couldn't make it display nicely.

Answer (score 0):

We solved the problem a different way thanks to one of my co-workers who is much more knowledgeable about Nginx and networking in general than I am. Instead of going the `location` route we went the `server_name` route.

What that means is that instead of extracting the IP from the $uri value we are using a subdomain. Here is an example of the server configuration that allowed us to make this work:

```
server {
    server_name ~^(?<ip>.+)\.devices\.com$;

    location / { 
        proxy_pass https://$ip;
    }
}
```

With the above configuration we can now use in the browser's URL box something like `http://172.10.10.1.devices.com/terminal/` and everything works as expected.